# Is it possible to iterate through a pandas dataframe in an LSTM prediction model?

Tags: arrays, pandas, iterator, lstm, prediction

I import the following modules:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Densr, Bidirectional, Dropout
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
```

---  code ---

`print("The predicted numbers are:",scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred).astype(int)[0])`
This will print an array of predicted numbers.

I would like to print an array of predicted numbers for a range of rows in the data. For example,

df.head(0) thru df.head(20)

I scoured the internet for a solution but could not find one. Is this even possible?

I tried the following:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

This only iterates through the rows in the data before it is processed

```
for column_name in df.iteritems():
    print(column_name)
```

This iterated over the columns also before data is processed

```
for index, row in np.array([scaled_to_predict]):
    print(row)
```

This returned a ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cn do it as in the example below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Bidirectional, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


data = np.random.randn(100, 5)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'])

train_size = int(len(df) * 0.8)
train = df[:train_size]
test = df[train_size:]

scaler = StandardScaler()
train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(train)
test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)

def create_sequences(X, y, time_steps=10):
    Xs, ys = [], []
    for i in range(len(X) - time_steps):
        Xs.append(X[i:i + time_steps])
        ys.append(y[i + time_steps])
    return np.array(Xs), np.array(ys)

X_train, y_train = create_sequences(train_scaled[:, :-1], train_scaled[:, -1])
X_test, y_test = create_sequences(test_scaled[:, :-1], test_scaled[:, -1])

X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, 10, 5)
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, 10, 5)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64, input_shape=(10, 5))))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001))

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1, shuffle=False)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

y_test_zeros = np.zeros((len(y_test), 4))
y_test_concat = np.hstack((y_test.reshape(-1,1), y_test_zeros))

y_pred_concat = np.hstack((y_pred, np.zeros((len(y_pred), 4))))
y_pred_scaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_concat)[:, 0].astype(int)


print("The predicted numbers are:")
for i in range(len(y_pred_scaled)):
    print(y_pred_scaled[i])
```

which returns:

```
The predicted numbers are:
0
0
0
0
1
-1
0
0
```

so, you simply need to do the following thing:

```
y_pred_concat = np.hstack((y_pred, np.zeros((len(y_pred), 4))))
y_pred_scaled = scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred_concat)[:, 0].astype(int)


print("The predicted numbers are:")
for i in range(len(y_pred_scaled)):
    print(y_pred_scaled[i])
```